# How to cancel a nestedlist's listchange event?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a button inside of a nestedlist's item template which when the user clicks I do not want to move between lists. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, a simple `return false` within the listener should do the trick

```
...
listeners:{
  listchange:function(){
    return false
  }
}
...
```

Hope this helps